# Calling javascript function on thymeleaf th:text template

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I am trying to attach returned text value of javascript function to thymeleaf th:text template.

Binding javascript function with `th:onclick` is possible.

Binding javascript function with `th:text` is possible?

I do not know whether it is possible or not.

Any suggestion?

```
Filename = Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.jpeg

function callBack (fiuleName) {
    // some logic
    return Abcde….jpeg
};
```

`file.getFileName()` gives fileName.

```
<span th:id="filename" th:text=“callBack(${file.getFileName()})”></span>
```

span tag is in the loop.

I want to use callBack function with th:text.

Comment: Thymeleaf is on the server, Javascript is on the client. You cannot in any simple way return from the client to the server and process that with Thymeleaf. **Please explain in more detail what you require.**

Comment: I want to apply filter through javascript function on filename which is returned from server. I want to pass full filename to javascript function and function returns short name for that filename. and that short name I want to display on browser.

Comment: Please give an example for a full and its short filename.

Comment: I updated in question. let me know whether it is clear now or not?

Comment: I don't think `th:text` allows anything like that. In my answer I show how you'd do that independent of what template engine you use on the serverside. Just do `<span class="filename" th:text=“${file.getFileName()}”></span>`. You might be able to use `<span th:text=“${file.getFileName()}” th:onload="callBack(${file.getFileName()})"></span>` but I don't know if `th:onload` even exists.

Comment: If it is not possible with th:text then this would be the alternative way to do it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So for the example I'm assuming a full filename (rendered on the browser) looks like this:

```
<div class="filename">FileName.full.file</div>
```

while what you want to show is

```
<div class="filename">FileName.file</div>
```

```js
// get a collection of all filename items in the DOM
const filenames = document.querySelectorAll('.filename');

// to make sure the elements are parsed, add the functionality to DOMContentLoaded
// which guarantees that the DOM is complete and all elements are accessible to JS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  for (const filename of [...filenames]) {
    filename.textContent = filename.textContent.replace('.full', '');
    filename.classList.add('transformed');
  }
})
```

```css
/* this will avoid the flash of non-transformed text to be visible before JS processes it */

.filename {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.filename.transformed {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="filename">FileName.full.file</div>
```

Comment: I have to assigned short file name dynamically in thymeleaf template. With css it is not possible. That is why I have created javascript function. But now problem is to use it with thymeleaf th:text template

Comment: I still don't understand what you need. Do you have the short filename on the serverside, or do you want to transform it to short filename using JS logic?

Comment: I want to transform it to short file name using javascript logic.

Comment: That's what happens in my answer. You need to show a long and its short filename so I can adjust the logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use javascript function with th:text

But

```
<script th:inline="javascript"> 
    var shortFileName = callBack([[file.getFileName()]]);
    $("#filename").text(shortFileName);
</script>
```

can be used in thymeleaf template.